# Jasmine Unit Tests run with Chutzpah on TFS Build Server fail....then pass

Tags: tfs, typescript, jasmine, chutzpah

We currently have an Asp.Net MVC application that leverages angularJs as our javascript framework.  We also use TypeScript when developing with angular.  Our unit tests are written with jasmine and the test runner is chutzpah.  Currently all unit tests (43 in total) are being run and are passing locally in the VS2012 Test Explorer.

We then configured our TFS build server to run the unit tests with chutzpah and while they are running, we are experiencing strange results.  As you can see below, unit tests were run - however, 43 is the number of unit tests we wrote, not 65.

[image]

[image]

Okay, 22 failed tests - it happens to the best of us.  However, the weird part is when we looked at the 'log' tab:

[image]

Immediately under the list of test failures is the complete list of tests that we wrote (43) with a passing status.

In summary, it looks like the unit tests are run twice: the first run fails all the tests, the second run passes.  Has anyone ever experienced this issue before?  Any help would be appreciated.

Also, I wanted to include the chutzpah.json file we are using - notice it is referencing .js files and excluding .ts files from test execution.

```
{
    "Framework": "jasmine",
    "RootReferencePathMode":"SettingsFileDirectory",        
    "TestHarnessLocationMode": "SettingsFileAdjacent",
    "References": [     
        { "Path": "../Scripts/angular.js" },
        { "Path": "../Scripts/angular-route.js" },
        { "Path": "../Scripts/angular-mocks.js" },
        { "Path": "../Scripts/angular-animate.js" },
        { "Path": "../Scripts/angular-cookies.js" },
        { "Path": "../Scripts/angular-resource.js" },
        { "Path": "../Scripts/angular-sanitize.js" },
        { "Path": "../Scripts/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap.js" },
        { "Path": "../Scripts/typings/_allReferences.js" },
        { "Path": "app.js" },
        { "Path": "core.js" },      
        { "Path": "models.js" },
        { "Path": "Directives", "Include": "*.js" },
        { "Path": "Services" "Include": "*.js" },
        {"Path": "app/tests/mocks.js"},
        {"Path": "app/services/" "Include": "*.js"},
        {"Path": "app/repositories/" "Include": "*.js"},
        {"Path": "app/controllers/" "Include": "*.js"},
        {"Path": "app/xModules/" "Include": "*.js"}
    ],
    "Tests": [
        { "Path": "app/tests", "Include": "*Spec*", "Exclude": "*.ts" }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hey--did you ever get this working?  How did you set up your tests to run on TFS also?

Comment: @BenLiyanage I'm struggling with the same thing. There is a [document](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah/) that I found useful, but it does seem to be incomplete.

Comment: I have not found a solution for this, and no longer have the project set up to verify/troubleshoot any proposed answers.